# IEEE754: guarantees on division results

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Consider:

[image: \x/10^y = z.5]

*x* is a positive integer with a maximum value which is unlikely to be above about 10,000,000.

*y* is a small integer which is >=0, with a maximum value of about 5; I can set an upper limit if necessary.

*z* is calculated and then rounded to the nearest integer, with halfway cases rounded upwards. I'm interested in cases where the numerically correct answer is rounded upwards, but double-precision 754 gives the 'wrong' answer, which will then be rounded downwards. So, in other words, the numerically-correct result has a fractional part which is >=0.5, but the fractional part of the actual result is <0.5.

The language I'm using doesn't give me access to the FPU setup, so I can only use default settings (primarily x86_64, Linux and Windows).

Do I just have to accept that some answers will be 'wrong', or can I put some limits on *x* and *y* which are guaranteed to give the required answer? Or is there an alternative calculation which will give the correct answer after rounding? If necessary, I can also change the definition of how *z* will be rounded if I can actually make guarantees about the result.

Comment: Do you have any particular IEEE 754 formats in mind? E.g., can we assume the binary64 format? Or are you also interested in binary32, or in other decimal or binary formats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming:

- *x* ≤ 10,000,000.
- 0 ≤ *y* ≤ 5.
- IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point is used, with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even.

Then the result of the division is never a number whose fraction part is less than ½ but that rounds to ½.

The greatest result occurs when *x* = 10,000,000 and *y* = 0, in which case *z* = 10,000,000. Then *z* has 24 bits in its integer part. The floating-point format has 53 bits in the significand, so 29 remain available for the fraction part. This means that any fraction part less than ½ − 2<sup>−30</sup> will be rounded to ½ − 2<sup>−29</sup> or less (because the bits available for the fraction are capable of making distinctions that fine—if the mathematical result is less than ½ − 2<sup>−30</sup>, there is a representable value closer to it than ½, so the lower value is used).

Therefore, only an exact mathematical result with a fraction in [½ − 2<sup>−30</sup>, ½) could be less than ½ but rounded up to ½. Let *z* be such a value, and let *t* be its fraction part.

From the statement of the problem, we know that *z* • 10<sup>*y*</sup> is an integer (*x*). Therefore *t* • 10<sup>*y*</sup> is an integer, and, even if *y* is less than 5, *t* • 10<sup>5</sup> is an integer.

Since *t* is in [½ − 2<sup>−30</sup>, ½), *t* • 10<sup>5</sup> is in [(½ − 2<sup>−30</sup>) • 10<sup>5</sup>, ½ • 10<sup>5</sup>) = [50,000 − 2<sup>−30</sup> • 10<sup>5</sup>, 50,000) = [50,000 - 0.0000931322574615478515625, 50,000).

Obviously, there are no integers in this interval, so no such *z* exists.

Comment: Thanks - that was very useful - sorry about the delay in getting back to you.